# Conformal Mapping of $\mathbb{D}$ onto itself taking $x$ to $y$

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I want to find a conformal mapping of the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$ onto itslef that takes 1/2 to 1/3.  Here is my attempt:

We know that $f(z)=\frac{z-a}{\bar{a}z-1}$ with $|a|<1$ maps $\mathbb{D}$ onto itself.  So, if we let $f(z)=\frac{1}{3}$ and $z=\frac{1}{2}$, then algebraically we can solve to get $a=\frac{5}{7}$.  Therefore the map $f(z)=\frac{z-\frac{5}{7}}{\frac{5z}{7}-1}$ will do the trick.
Would this work?  Thank you!

Comment: The conjugate of $5/7$ is itself not its opposite...

Comment: @guy3141 Why do you think there is a problem for $z=0$ ?

Comment: The derivative of $f(z)=(z-a)/(az-1)$ at $z=0$ is $a^2-1 \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation of a possible value of $a$ is correct. But your error is to have written that the conjugate of $5/7$ is $-5/7$ instead of $5/7$ plainly.

Therefore the function is $$f(z)=\dfrac{z-\tfrac57}{\tfrac57 z -1}$$

Here is a way to have an idea of how function $f$ operates (on the left the disk with concentric circles and radial lines orthogonal to them ; on the right, their images by function $f$. Please note that orthogonality is preserved. Point $1/2$ and its image $1/3$ have been represented by a little star.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!  I believe my original function had that the conujugate of 5/7 is just 5/7 too.  Thank you!

Comment: Those pictures are awesome!  I can't thank you enough!